# ways to express things happen in the near future

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to learn some phrases/ words that used to express the things that will happen in the near future.

For example,

> I am going to visit Japan soon

I know the word `recently`, but it can only be used for things in the near past right? so what are some of the "future version" of recently?

also, is this sentence valid

> I am going to visit Japan within the next few days

Comment: I doubt you'll find better than *soon.*

Comment: @Davo - Perhaps so, but _soon_ is inherently vague.

Answer (score 2):

> I am going to visit Japan within the next few days

That sentence is perfectly valid. Some alternatives to the word "soon" include "shortly", "in a little while", etc. You could also say "weeks", "months" instead of "days" in the above quote, of course. "Shortly" implies that you will be visiting Japan very soon, perhaps you'll be on the plane within the next few hours. "In a little while" could mean a longer time, like within the coming weeks.

It is acceptable to say

> I plan to visit Japan in the near future.